# MYSQL Innerjoin only show one record

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am busy with a ticket systeem and i have the question in a table, users information in an other table and the responses in an other table.

What i want is to get the Question (Table 1) with the user information by user ID and all the responses (also with user information by id)

Now i have the following code:

```
  public function ticketSingle($id=""){
  $sql = "
  SELECT ticketSubmitted.*, users.Name, users.email, users.phone, ticketResponse.*
  FROM ticketSubmitted

  INNER JOIN users
  ON users.id = ticketSubmittedUserId

  JOIN ticketResponse
  ON ticketId = ticketSubmittedID

  WHERE ticketSubmittedID = '".$id."'
  ";

  $result = $this->run($sql, $bind);
  return $result[0];
}
```

Table 1 = ticketSubmitted (the question, with an userID "ticketSubmittedUserId")
Table 2 = users (The user information)
Table 3 = ticketResponse (The table with the reactions)

But if i Print the results i get only one record of the TicketResponse and what i want is all the reactions.

Can someone help me out?

This is what the function return:

```
Array
(
    [ticketSubmittedID] => 1
    [ticketSubmittedUserId] => 1
    [ticketSubmittedDate] => 2018-02-05 16:00:00
    [ticketSubmittedTitle] => Question Title
    [ticketSubmittedMessage] => Hello World!
    [ticketSubmittedUserIp] => XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
    [ticketSubmittedStatus] => 1
    [Name] => John Doe
    [email] => john@doe.com
    [phone] => 0612345678
    [ticketResponseId] => 1
    [ticketId] => 1
    [ticketUserId] => 2
    [ticketMessage] => Hello Reaction
    [ticketDate] => 2018-02-05 17:05
    [ticketIp] => XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
)
```

Comment: What is `$this`, or more precisely what is the array that `$this->run()` returns?  Your function `ticketSingle()` only returns the first element of that array...

Comment: You use `inner join` and `join`, but they are the same. Not a problem per se, but it may indicate that you have a misunderstanding there, and maybe are looking for a different kind of join (left join, maybe)?

Comment: Haha, Meneer Aart, btw. :o)

Comment: Haha, thats my second name ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning only the first row  `return $result[0];`   0 in the first index of the result. so you should return all eg:

```
return $result;
```

and loop over the result for manage what you need

```
 foreach($result as $key => $value){
  echo $value['ticketResponseId'];     
 }
```

You can check the real return content using

```
 var_dump($result);
```